# Finding the types of singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, functions

I am working on the following:

Let $f : \mathbb C \setminus \{1,2\} \to \mathbb C$ be defined by

\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)-2}{z-2} + \frac{\cos(1/(z-2))}{(z-2)^2}+\frac{\cos(z-1)-1}{z-1}.
\end{align*}

I want to find the types of singularities at the points 1 and 2. I already found that we have a pole of order one at the point 1. But I don't know how I can find this for the point 2. I tried to find $\lim_{z \to 2} (z-2)^2 f(z)$ but this limit does not exist.

Please help.

Comment: Could you explain how you found the pole of order one at $z=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Essential singularity at $z = 2$. See by expanding the function $\cos(\frac{1}{z-2})$ into series

Comment: Or, by the fact that the limit indeed doesn't exist (not even in the general sense).